# Calculus 3 volume

Tags: calculus, volume

> Set up a triple integral to compute the volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by the cone $z = 1 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the plane $x +y+z=1$.

I wanted to use polar coordinates for this. I got the theta integral to be equal to be zero from $\pi/2$ and the $r$ integral to be $0$ to $1$. But I don’t know how to set up the inner most integral. Any ideas would help.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far? You'll find people are more responsive when you show your effort. It also helps us figure out how best to explain our solutions.

Comment: For $x \geq 0 , y\geq0 , z\geq 0$ you got the inner intergral limit as $\phi = 0 to $\frac{\pie}{2}$. But specially the above condition should be satisfied about the first octant.

Comment: I tried setting the plane and cone equal to each other to find the region where they intersect, but I got zero.

Answer (score 1):

I guess from polar coordinates here you mean cylindrical coordinates.

Level surface of $z = c$ , where $c \in (0,1)$, would have cross-section like this.

$\hskip 2.5 in$[image]

Here ,$\angle ACB = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$. Let $\angle BAC = \theta  \Rightarrow \angle ABC = \dfrac{3 \pi}{4}  - \theta$, On using sine rule, one can find that $$ x = \dfrac{r}{\sqrt{2}} cosec \bigg( \dfrac{3 \pi}{4}  - \theta \bigg) $$
It should be obvious that $ x \le \rho \le r$. It should be obvious that $r = 1 -z$

For the given region $1 - x - y \le z \le 1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \implies 1 - r(\cos \theta + \sin \theta) \le z \le 1 - r$.

Recall $$dV = \iiint r dr d\theta d z$$  $$ \implies dV = \int^{\pi /2}_0 \int_x^r \int^{1 - r(\cos \theta + \sin \theta}_{1 - r} r dr d \theta d z $$

Comment: Why did you go from x to 1 for the second integral ?

Comment: @JustinD Careless mistake, thanks for pointing out. Fine, now?

Comment: yes, cylindrical coordinates and z= const. slices is the best choice (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The cone $z = 1 - \sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ has vertex $(0,0,1)$

The plane $x+y+z = 1$ intersects this vertex.

The two surfaces do not define a solid.

Even if they didn't intersect at the vertex, if we used the plane $x+y+z = 0$ it would be "too steep."  That is, it would cut the plane at such an angle as to create a half a hyperbola.  You would need a plane like $x+y+4z = 0$ to create an a ellipse for the bottom of the cone.